# How can I add a second item to an observablecollection using an entry and a button without overwriting the first item?

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms, observablecollection

I want the user to add items to an observablecollection through an entry in my Xamarin.forms app. After tapping the "Add" button I want to add an item with the information the user just submitted. This will then be displayed in a listview.

```
                public MainPage(string image = "@drawable/icon", string name = "", string address = "")
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = this;

        PopulateListView(image, name, address);

    }


public void PopulateListView(string image, string name, string address)
        {
            Zones = new ObservableCollection<ViewModels.ZoneViewModel>();
        Zones.Add(new ViewModels.ZoneViewModel { Image = image, Name = name, Address = address });

        Application.Current.Properties["zoneslist"] = Zones;

        DisplayAlert("t", "t", "OK");
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        if (Application.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("zoneslist"))
        {
            // Put the contents of the "zoneslist" key into a variable as a string.
            var savedZones = Application.Current.Properties["zoneslist"] as ObservableCollection<ViewModels.ZoneViewModel>;

            // Set the listviews' itemssource to the savedzones list.
            zonesList.ItemsSource = savedZones;
        }
    }
```

What I'm doing now, I think, is overwriting the ZoneViewModel object. So one item shows up in my listview, and if I try to add another item it will overwrite the first one.

Can anyone help me?

Edit: Added all code that is used for the listview

Comment: I don't think it's possible to help without more code. Can you add all the code that relates to this ListView?

Comment: Show more code.

Comment: @LuccasClezar, I've added some code.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I've figured it out. What I was doing wrong: Creating a new instance of the observablecollection everytime right before adding an item to my list. So everytime PopulateListview() was called it would overwrite the current instance of the observablecollection.

What I changed to fix this, is I created an instance of the observablecollection instantly on the same line.

```
private static ObservableCollection<ViewModels.ZoneViewModel> Zones = new ObservableCollection<ViewModels.ZoneViewModel>();
```

instead of doing the following, and creating the instance later.

```
private ObservableCollection<ViewModels.ZoneViewModel> Zones { get; set; }
```

So; to answer my question: I wasn't overwriting the first item, but the entire list. How to fix that is above.